# Installing Froyo on Milestone

Tags: motorola-milestone, 2.2-froyo

Is there a way to install Froyo on the Motorola Milestone?

I understand that Motorola is planning a deployment of this release in Q1 2011 but I just wish I had it now!

Comment: See: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo

Comment: Official update has been released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stock Froyo?  No, not at the moment.

Custom ROM?  [Take a look at XDA Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=670), there are some ROMs currently in progress, but might be unstable on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Froyo is released for the Milestone
Go to this page to get it from motorola: http://www.motorola.com/staticfiles/Support/GB-EN/froyo/milestonenotification.htm